# need to check if filename contains the date.default property in ant script

Tags: ant, build

Here is my script: 
`

```
        description="--> emails any file from a specified location">
    <tstamp>
        <format property="date.default" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" 
                offset="-1" unit="day" />
    </tstamp>
    <echo message="${date.default}" />
    <for param="file">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="${report.dir}">
                <include name="**/*file*.doc" />
                    <contains text=" ${date.default}"/>                 
            </fileset>
        </path>
    </for>`
```

Comment: your quoted build excerpt looks truncated, the for loop is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to iterate over the set of files with names that match both the word 'file' (as you use this in the include element) and the value of '${date.default}'.  You probably don't need to use a [selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html) for that - the include directive is usually enough for file name matches.  For example, you might use:

```
<include name="**/*file*${date.default}*.doc" />
```

The [`contains` selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#containsselect) is for matching *content* of files, rather than the file names.  If you have a complex filename-based matching rule, then you may need to make use of the [`filename` selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#filenameselect) in combination with includes, and possibly excludes.  But 'filename' selectors are normally only needed when selection is based on filename plus some other criteria.